# Verify credentials with python and kerberos

Tags: python, kerberos, gssapi

I'm working on a project for university. I set up a server which has to verify several credentials (username and password) with a kerberos 5 server (which is a seperate server in my network). I don't have to perform any actions with the rights of those users, just check if the combination of username and password is valid. My project is written in python on Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

This question is related to a [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682341/verify-credentials-using-krb5-and-gssapi-python) of mine

I managed to verify the credentials with gssapi but somebody told me:

> Just an unrelated note -- I don't know how your project is structured,
>   but if you're doing this password verification in the server then it's
>   not really making good use of Kerberos... it's just using the KDC as a
>   dumb credential database but not actually protecting the credentials

What would be the correct/a better way to verify credentials?

That's how I managed to verify:

```
import gssapi

server_name = gssapi.Name('krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@')

username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"

user = gssapi.Name(base=username, name_type=gssapi.NameType.user)
bpass = password.encode('utf-8')
result = False
try:
    creds = gssapi.raw.acquire_cred_with_password(user, bpass, usage='initiate')
    creds = creds.creds
    context = gssapi.SecurityContext(name=server_name, creds=creds, usage='initiate')
    result = True
except AttributeError:
    print("AttributeError")
except gssapi.exceptions.GSSError as er:
    print(er)
# acquire_cred_with_password returns a wrapper, we want the creds
# object inside this wrapper
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `gssapi.raw.acquire_cred_with_password(user, bpass, usage='initiate')` is fully sufficient to obtain a TGT. Nothing else is necessary.